# Hacer una query en Laravel con una tabla pivote

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hola buenos días estoy intentando hacer una query entre tres tablas con una de ellas es la pivote. Se trata que tengo una tabla para guardar las viviendas, otra para guardar los servicios que puede tener las viviendas y por último una pivote que almacena la id de la vivienda y la id del servicio que tiene.

La idea es mostrar todos los servicio en una iteración y lo que si tenga la vivienda ponerles un check verde y si no lo tiene poner una x en rojo.

Mis tablas son las siguientes:

**Vivienda**

| id | name | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Reformado con plaza de garaje incluida | v-849-reformado-con-plaza-de-garaje-incluida |
| 2 | Reformado con ascensor | v-850-reformado-con-ascensor |

**Servicio**

| servicio_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ascensor |
| 2 | Armarios empotrados |

**vivienda_servicio**

| vivienda_vivienda_id | servicio_servicio_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |

Bien, supongo que se puede hacer con relaciones, pero no es algo que se me de muy bien, entonces estoy haciendolo así:

**Controlador**

```
$servicios = ViviendaServicio::
        join('servicio', 'vivienda_servicio.servicio_servicio_id', '=', 'servicio.servicio_id')
        ->where('vivienda_servicio.vivienda_vivienda_id', $propiedad->id)
        ->select('vivienda_servicio.*', 'servicio.nombre', 'servicio.servicio_id')->get();
 //////
$serviciosSeleccionados = ViviendaServicio::where('vivienda_servicio.vivienda_vivienda_id', $propiedad->id)->pluck('servicio_servicio_id');
//////
$todosServicios = Servicio::whereNotIn('servicio_id', $serviciosSeleccionados)->get();
```

Luego en mi vista los itero así:

```
<div class="cuadroDetalles">
   <div class="row">
      @foreach ($servicios as $item)
         <div class="col-4">
           <li>
             {{ $item->nombre }} 
             <span class="pull-right">
                <span class="optionListado"><i class="far fa-check-circle siTiene"></i></span>
             </span>
           </li>
         </div>
       @endforeach
       @foreach ($todosServicios as $item2)
          <div class="col-4">
            <li>
               {{ $item2->nombre }} 
               <span class="pull-right">
                 <span class="optionListado"><i class="far fa-times-circle noTiene"></i></span>
               </span>
            </li>
          </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Esto está funcionando, pero el problema es que me saca primero los que si tiene y luego los que no y yo quiero que me los saque todos con el mismo orden siempre y ponga el check en los que si y la cruz en los que no. ¿Eso es posible?

Pongo como consulto en mi controlador la vivienda que estoy viendo.

```
$propiedad = Vivienda::with('etiqueta')
             ->with('poblacion')
             ->with('elDistrito')
             ->with('galeria')
             ->where('slug', $slug)->first();
```

---

En respuesta a **Jonathan Orta**:
Esto es lo que recibo con un `dd($serviciosSeleccionados);`

```
  0 => 1
    1 => 2
    2 => 3
    3 => 4
    4 => 8
    5 => 19
    6 => 20
    7 => 21
    8 => 26
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes modificar un array de todos los servicios utilizando los que ya existen

```
$propiedad = Vivienda::with('etiqueta')
             ->with('poblacion')
             ->with('elDistrito')
             ->with('galeria')
             ->where('slug', $slug)->first();

//Obtienes los id de los servicios que tiene
$serviciosSeleccionados = ViviendaServicio::where('vivienda_vivienda_id', $propiedad->id)->get()->pluck('servicio_servicio_id');

//Al utilizar map, indicas cuales tiene, añadiendo una propiedad que puede ser 'tiene' que va a tener un valor true o false dependiendo si el servicio esta incluido en los servicios de la vivienda
$servicios = Servicio::orderBy('nombre')->get()->map(function ($servicio) use ($serviciosSeleccionados) {
    $servicio->tiene = in_array($servicio->id, $serviciosSeleccionados);
    return $servicio;
});


// En la vista, recorres todos los servicios y la propiedad 'tiene' te permite saber si existe o no
@foreach ($servicios as $item)
         <div class="col-4">
           <li>
             {{ $item->nombre }} 
             <span class="pull-right">
                <span class="optionListado"><i class="far fa-check-circle {{ $servicios->tiene ? 'siTiene' : 'noTiene' }}"></i></span>
             </span>
           </li>
         </div>
       @endforeach
```

Comment: Hola @Jonathan Orta no me funciona. Primero que es esto `$servicio->tiene` también he corregido un parentesis de más en la query de servicios y `$serviciosSelecciones` de donde sale? después de cambiar `$serviciosSelecciones` por `$serviciosSeleccionados` y quitar el parentesis me devuelve esto: `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given`

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta editada

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, cambio `name` por `nombre` y quito el parentesis que sobra pero me sigue arrojando lo mismo @JonathanOrta

Comment: Despues de que obtienes `$serviciosSeleccionados` has de un `dd($serviciosSeleccionados)` para ver que datos obtienes

Comment: He puesto lo que recibo al final de mi pregunta @JonathanOrta

Comment: Sigue retornando el mismo error, tienes un array como segundo parámetro del in_array, no debería recibor un objeto